# Как заполнить двумерный массив из одномерного определенными способом?

Tags: c++, массивы, матрицы

У меня есть массив arr[18] = [-1 0 3 -8 15 -24 35 -48 63 -80 99 -120 143 -168 195 -224 255 -288]
Необходимо заполнить двумерный массив таким образом:

```
[-1 35 143
0 -48 168
......]
```

То есть размером 6x3 слева на право и сверху вниз по столбцам.
Попробовал вот так, но не работает:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        array2D[i][j] = array1D[i * j % 6];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Примерно так.

```
int k = 0;
for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        array2D[i][j] = array1D[k++];
    }
}
```

Или так:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        array2D[i][j] = array1D[j*6+i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    int arr[18] = {-1, 0 , 3, -8, 15, -24, 35, -48, 63, -80, 99, -120, 143, -168, 195, -224, 255, -288};
    int array2D[6][3];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
        array2D[i % 6][i / 6] = arr[i];
    }

    // output
    for(int r = 0; r < 6; r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
            cout << array2D[r][c] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
-1 35 143 
0 -48 -168 
3 63 195 
-8 -80 -224 
15 99 255 
-24 -120 -288
```